# identify file system format of a disk type in java like ntfs, fat16/32 or ext

Tags: java, filesystems

Is there any way to find out the file system format of a disk in java?

For example for a windows hard drive it could be NTFS, for zip drives it is FAT32.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

N.B. This is only valid for Java running on Windows system:

Using JNA, you can call Win32 Kernel32's **GetVolumeInformation()** to retrieve *lpFileSystemNameBuffer* parameter which `receives the name of the file system, for example, the FAT file system or the NTFS file system` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364993(v=vs.85).aspx

**Kernel32.java**:

```
package filesystem;


import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.DWORD;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;
import com.sun.jna.win32.W32APIFunctionMapper;
import com.sun.jna.win32.W32APITypeMapper;

public interface Kernel32 extends StdCallLibrary {

    final static Map<String, Object> WIN32API_OPTIONS = new HashMap<String, Object>() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        {
            put(Library.OPTION_FUNCTION_MAPPER, W32APIFunctionMapper.UNICODE);
            put(Library.OPTION_TYPE_MAPPER, W32APITypeMapper.UNICODE);
        }
    };

    public Kernel32 INSTANCE = (Kernel32) Native.loadLibrary("Kernel32", Kernel32.class, WIN32API_OPTIONS);

    /*
    BOOL WINAPI GetVolumeInformation(
            __in_opt   LPCTSTR lpRootPathName,
            __out      LPTSTR lpVolumeNameBuffer,
            __in       DWORD nVolumeNameSize,
            __out_opt  LPDWORD lpVolumeSerialNumber,
            __out_opt  LPDWORD lpMaximumComponentLength,
            __out_opt  LPDWORD lpFileSystemFlags,
            __out      LPTSTR lpFileSystemNameBuffer,
            __in       DWORD nFileSystemNameSize
            );
     */
    public boolean GetVolumeInformation(
            String lpRootPathName,
            char[] lpVolumeNameBuffer,
            DWORD nVolumeNameSize,
            IntByReference lpVolumeSerialNumber,
            IntByReference lpMaximumComponentLength,
            IntByReference lpFileSystemFlags,
            char[] lpFileSystemNameBuffer,
            DWORD nFileSystemNameSize
            );

    public int GetLastError();
}
```

**VolumeInformation.java**:

```
package filesystem;

import ping.Kernel32;

import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.DWORD;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference;

public class VolumeInformation {

    static void getFileSystemName(){
        char[] lpVolumeNameBuffer = new char[256];
        DWORD nVolumeNameSize = new DWORD(256);
        IntByReference lpVolumeSerialNumber = new IntByReference();
        IntByReference lpMaximumComponentLength = new IntByReference();
        IntByReference lpFileSystemFlags = new IntByReference();

        char[] lpFileSystemNameBuffer = new char[256];
        DWORD nFileSystemNameSize = new DWORD(256);

        lpVolumeSerialNumber.setValue(0);
        lpMaximumComponentLength.setValue(256);
        lpFileSystemFlags.setValue(0);

        Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetVolumeInformation(
                "C:\\", 
                lpVolumeNameBuffer, 
                nVolumeNameSize, 
                lpVolumeSerialNumber, 
                lpMaximumComponentLength, 
                lpFileSystemFlags, 
                lpFileSystemNameBuffer, 
                nFileSystemNameSize);

        System.out.println("Last error: "+Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetLastError()+"\n\n");

        String fs = new String(lpFileSystemNameBuffer);
        System.out.println(fs.trim());

    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getFileSystemName();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of Java are you using?

If Java 7 - Check out this API - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystems.html

Outside of that I know System.getProperty and Runtime have methods to grab information on the disk being used but nothing that specifically calls out the File System type (NTFS, FAT32, etc.)

Comment: How does that API tell you the format of the filesystem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`FileStore`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/FileStore.html) API.

```java
Files.getFileStore(Path.of(".")).type()
```

This will return the filesystem type of the given path as reported by the operating system, e.g. `"NTFS"`, `"ext4"`, `"tmpfs"`, etc.

The same filesystem may report a different value on different operating systems. e.g. `"FAT32"` vs. `"vfat"`.