# How to check if filesystem supports links and symlinks in Java

Tags: java, file, filesystems, java-7, nio

The [Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createSymbolicLink%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...%29) class introduced in Java 7 has methods for handling links and symlinks but only as *optional operations*.

Is there any way of determining at runtime if a file system supports these operations before actually invoking the respective methods or do I need to call them and then catch the exception?

Classes like [FileSystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html) or [FileStore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileStore.html) do not seem to contain anything in that regard (or I overlooked it).

Comment: The documentation says: UnsupportedOperationException - if the implementation does not support symbolic links or the array contains an attribute that cannot be set atomically when creating the symbolic link

Comment: Maybe this one can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441258/identify-file-system-format-of-a-disk-type-in-java-like-ntfs-fat16-32-or-ext

Comment: @Akira that's what I meant by catching the exception ;)

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any general approach that will work without relying on an `UnsupportedOperationException` or some other exception.

You could use a heuristic that assumes that only subclasses of `BasicFileAttributesView` support symbolic linking.

---

Note: The approach below will not work because `FileAttributeViews` and file attributes are not the same concept:

I did not get `isSymbolicLink` as one of the supported attributes with the following code on OS X 10.8.4:

```
package com.mlbam.internal;

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.FileStore;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class MainClass {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainClass.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("FileStore.supportsFileAttributeView('isSymbolicLink'): " 
                + Files.getFileStore(Paths.get("/")).supportsFileAttributeView("isSymbolicLink"));
            // Got: FileStore.supportsFileAttributeView('isSymbolicLink'): false
            System.out.println(FileSystems.getDefault().supportedFileAttributeViews());
            // Got: [basic, owner, unix, posix]
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

---

Original Answer:

If you have an instance of `FileStore`, you can use [`FileStore.supportsFileAttributeView("isSymbolicLink")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileStore.html#supportsFileAttributeView%28java.lang.String%29)

Or, if you have an instance of `FileSystem`, you can check that resulting `Set<String>` from [`FileSystem.supportedFileAttributeViews()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#supportedFileAttributeViews%28%29) contains the String `"isSymbolicLink"`.

---

You can get the `FileStore` associated with a `Path` using [`Files.getFileStore(Path)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#getFileStore%28java.nio.file.Path%29)

One way of getting the `FileSystem` is via [`FileSystems.getDefault()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystems.html#getDefault%28%29)

---

Comment: Hm, surprisingly this does not seem to work on a win-machine with NTFS - thought it supported symlinks? Gonna try it on linux later...

Comment: @shutefan, it looks like you're correct and my answer might not be. It didn't work with OS X either. Not sure how to address this. Do I flag the answer? I'd rather not delete so others can see this approach doesn't work.

Comment: thanks for trying out! I'd rather keep the answer for a reference so that others don't try the same in vain.

Comment: Agreed. In any case, for most practical purposes I bet people can use [`Files.isSymbolicLink(Path)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/links.html#detect) (please note that this is not documented to throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`)

Comment: The `supportsFileAttributeView` method takes the name of a FileAttributeView, *not* the name of a file attribute.  That's why it always returns false for you.  Similarly, `FileSystem.supportsFileAttributeViews` returns the names of FileAttributeViews, not the names of file attributes.  See [`Files.getAttribute`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#getAttribute%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29) for a description of the two types of names.

Comment: +1 @VGR, I'll update the answer tomorrow (or feel free to edit for me).