# Get partition name from drive letter and vice versa

Tags: java, windows, mount-point, drive-letter

The program I'm working on needs to access removable drives. Normally this wouldn't be a problem, because the mountpoint should stay the same (e.g.: On Ubuntu my phone's SD card gets mounted at `/media/sebastian/GT-S5830/`) But on Windows there are the drive letters, which can vary. (Same phone: Once `E:\`, after plugging in while camera was mounted at `E:`, it became `F:` and stayed.)

So I want to solve this by not saving the drive letter, but the partition name.

E.g.: When setting up, the path `E:\DCIM\Camera\` was given. Now I want to do the following:

- Get name of the partition mounted at `E:`
- Save path to given directory as something like `<partname>:\DCIM\Camera\`
- When accessing the device, resolve drive letter of partition named `partname`
- Build path by concatenating drive letter and the path-part after the colon.

How can I get the partition name by giving the mountpoint on Windows and vice versa with Java?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to explore `FileSystemView` to get a lot more information about the file system. More assorted examples [here](http://littletutorials.com/2008/03/10/getting-file-system-details-in-java/).

For your cause you might want to get a handle on the removable disk and do something with the info:

```
FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
        File[] files = File.listRoots();

        File[] roots = fsv.getRoots();
        for (int i = 0; i < roots.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Root: " + roots[i]);
        }

        for (File fi : files) {
            if (fsv.getSystemTypeDescription(fi).contains("Local Disk")
                    || fsv.getSystemTypeDescription(fi).contains(
                            "Removable Disk")) {
                System.out.println(fsv.getSystemDisplayName(fi));
            }

        }
```

**Output:**

```
Root: C:\Users\popofibo\Desktop
Local Disk (C:)
Recovery (D:)
Removable Disk (E:)
```

You might want to check the Windows disks' volume information using JNA if need be - more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441258/identify-file-system-format-of-a-disk-type-in-java-like-ntfs-fat16-32-or-ext/9441330#9441330).