# Is there a way to find out the underlying filesystem of a folder in Java?

Tags: java, filesystems

I'd like to generate files and folders in a folder using Java. Prior to that, I'd like to know the filesystem I'm wrting to (e.g. `ext3`, `ext4`, `NTFS`,...). Is there a way to do that?

If not: is there a way to find out limits of the underlying filesystem? (e.g. `ext3` does only allow `32000` INODEs per folder)

Comment: could this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441258/identify-file-system-format-of-a-disk-type-in-java-like-ntfs-fat16-32-or-ext

Comment: @Edward I haven't tried this my self but looks like the answer may lie in the [FileSystems](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystems.html) class added to JDK7

Comment: You can do that by using `.getFileSystem()` on a `Path` then playing with this filesystem's `.getFileStores()` and `.getRootDirectories()`; however this remains a heuristic... THe fact is that a `FileStore`'s `type()`, at least under Linux, returns the filesystem type, and the `name()` _may_ contain the mount point.

Comment: @fge got it wrong..deleting my ans.Thanks

Comment: @fge can you write an answer from your comment; I'd like to accept it.