# Java - determine disk format (RAW or FS)

Tags: java, windows, filesystems

Let's say I have a windows host, holding 10 disks:
Half of them are in RAW format and the other half are in some FileSystem format.
I'm looking for a way to determine, from within java code, which drive is in RAW format and which is in FileSystem format.
Till now, I was able to gain information (such as capacity, block size, index and more) about the disks using WMI queries, but I couldn't find a way to determine what is the disk format.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441258/identify-file-system-format-of-a-disk-type-in-java-like-ntfs-fat16-32-or-ext

Comment: This is not exactly what I'm looking for...
I don't need to know what kind of FS but if it is FS or not (= RAW).
I need something which accepts as input the disk name (PHYSICAL_DRIVE_1 for example) and returns if it is formatted with FS or if it is RAW

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to determine the disk format via diskpart utility.
I'm running detail disk on all of the disks and then parsing the output to know whether it is RAW/FS (the output is different for RAW/FS disks).
My script basically looks like:

```
select disk 1
detail disk
...
select disk n
detail disk
```